# How to show that

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Ok, so I've just been banging my head on this one for a bit. This is something I need to prove that:
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k\dfrac{\ln|k|^p}{k^q}$$
converges. Obviously, if I can show that the limit of $\dfrac{\ln|n|^p}{n^q}\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, I can use the alternating series test. Fairly simple... or so I assumed, like a moron.

So far, I tried differentiating $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln(x)^p}{x^q}$, but I got lost in all the cases. If $p=1$, the derivative is negative when $x>e^{1/q}$. I also know that, for sufficiently large $n$, $\ln(n)<n^c$ for any $c>0$, but when we throw in that second exponential on the log function, I lost my bearings and awoke hours later, under my desk, weeping.

I don't want anyone to give me the answer, but a hint (or a push) in the right direction would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Repeated application of  L'Hospital's Rule:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{ln(x)^p}{x^q}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{pln(x)^{p-1}x^{-1}}{qx^{q-1}}$$

Comment: I actually misread problem before the equations were edited -- so I did the case $[ln(k)]^p$ -- but the same idea applies to $ln[k^p]$

Comment: I think you read it correctly the first time. Thanks, that was super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

$\ln |k|^p = p\ln |k|$.  Then use L'Hopital's once or twice on 
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p\ln |k|}{k^q}$$

Comment: I'm afraid the function is quantity (ln|k|) raised to the power p, not ln|k^p|.